# How do I dual boot over two SSDs?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, linux-mint

I currently have a spare SSD and would like to install a version of Linux on it.  My other SSD has a Windows 7 install on it.  Is there a way that I can when turning the computer on get a menu which lets me pick which OS I would like to use?

I have heard of dual booting but this seems to be if I wanted to install two or more OS's on the same drive, where I would like to have an OS on a separate drive but still get an option menu when I turn the computer on so I can choose which OS to use.

Is this possible and how would I achieve it?  I am most likely going to use [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/) as the Linux OS if this makes a difference.

I realise one way to do this would be to change the priority in the BIOS boot menu each time to put the drive with the install I want to use at the top, but this doesn't feel like a good solution.

Comment: It would be far easier to just use the BIOS boot menu.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier initially but if another solution exists then I would be interested in finding it out.  The menu will enable others who use the computer to still boot into windows without having to change BIOS settings.

Comment: It is possible to get grub to do what you want, but it would far easier just to educate whoever else uses the computer to select the correct drive.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out by installing Linux Mint on my secondary SSD and setting the boot priority in my BIOS settings for that SSD to be higher than the SSD with the windows installation a boot menu appears by default.

This boot menu enables you to select which OS you would like to boot into and you do not have to do any additional configuration to get this working.